# trying to write a list in to csv file python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

```
list = ['Jan', '34', 'Mar', '65']

with open("list.csv", "w", newline='') as file:
     writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
     writer.writerows(list)
```

What I am getting in the CSV file is:

```
J,a,n
3,4
M,a,r
6,5
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
Jan,34
Mar,65
```

Can you help send me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2):

list needs the folowing syntax to work:

```
list = [['Jan', '34'], ['Mar', '65']]
```

Comment: So I cannot write into the CSV file the way the list is and get my desired outcome?

Comment: No, because it cannot make an inference about the columns count. Needs an explicit syntax